# Several issues with my php MVC with the correct path

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

Building a small php MVC tool but I ran into a couple of issues.

The first issue is that the resources(assets) need to have the public folder name inside the path, which I dont want

```
//current
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/assets/core.css">
//what I want 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/core.css">
```

The second issue is that routing does not work. Well all routes do work but when its just a slash it will redirect back to localhost(in my case). I do need to navigate back home.

```
   <ul>
       <li>
           <a href="/">Home</a>// will redirect to localhost
       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="about">About</a>//this works /project-x/about
       </li>
   </ul>
```

**project structure**

```
project-x/
-.htaccess
-public/
--assets/
---style.css
--index.php
-app/
-src/
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Stop processing if already in the /public directory
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L]

# Static resources if they exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1 [L]

# Route all other requests
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You should set your web servers document root to be the public folder. If you need to add `/public` in front of the assets, it most likely means that you have it set to the folder above.

Comment: I would also recommend that you use a proper [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) which will make it much easier to create more custom routes. It also makes your code more portable since you write the routes in your code instead of in htaccess (which is only for Apache web server).